# Javascript animate() scrolling does not work as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

When I use the code below, it gets very glitchy.

After the animation is complete, I scroll and the page (document) bounces around.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(' .nav, .learn-more').click(function(event){
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+event.target.id+".featurette").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Please see the demo on [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/Zachzhao/codebits/Apcux4/).

Comment: Did you mean `$(document).ready` not `(document).ready`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is a Professional Q & A site. Please visit [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bouncing happens when the animation didn't finish yet and the script would keep the page scrolling, then you try to counter-scroll, and due to the way jQuery animations work, your counter-scrolling gets reset by the continuation of the scrolling animation.

Upon looking at your [linked example](http://www.codecademy.com/Zachzhao/codebits/Apcux4), I found out why your animation was jumpy. The selector you use for attaching the click handler is `$(' .nav, .learn-more')`, and in your HTML, there's 2 `.nav`s, one being the child of the other:

> `<div class="`***`nav`***`">`
>       `<div class="container">`
>           `<ul class="pull-left`***`nav`***`nav-pills">`
>               `<li><a id="" href="#">Home</a></li>`

Because of this, the animation is called twice, causing the flickering. You should modify your selector to `$('.nav .nav, .learn-more')`, or use something more unique like `$('.nav.nav-pills, .learn-more')`.

```
$('.nav .nav, .learn-more').click(function(event){
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#"+event.target.id+".featurette").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Here's the fixed code in the code sharing platform of your choice: http://www.codecademy.com/DJDavid98/codebits/GSoDQf

Comment: I believe that it finished the animation. Check this similar example and mine: [Another test](http://www.codecademy.com/Zachzhao/codebits/Nko89X/)

Comment: @Zachzhao After I've waited for the animation to finish, I was able to scroll the page normally.

Comment: Thank you. I was using the same class because I used bootstrap.